# accessing linux based iphdr and tcphdr

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I am doing some network programming. I am trying to create tcp and ip headers. I found in readings that there are two ways to do this 1) linux based and 2) BSD based.

I want to this using the linux method, essentially including linux/ip.h and linux/tcp.h
The header type I am looking for is

```
     struct tcphdr {
    unsigned short source;
    unsigned short dest;
    unsigned long seq;
    unsigned long ack_seq;  
    unsigned short doff:4;
    unsigned char syn;
    unsigned short window;  
    unsigned short check;
    unsigned short urg_ptr;
```

};

But i am getting this :

```
    struct tcphdr {
       u_short th_sport;
       u_short th_dport;
       tcp_seq th_seq;
       tcp_seq th_ack;
       u_int   th_x2:4,
             th_off:4;
       u_char  th_flags;
       u_short th_win;        
       u_short th_sum;        
       u_short th_urp;        
 };
```

Now, I am using Xcode on mac for coding this in c++. However when I do a #include it gives me an error that "Header file not found"

Can anyone let me know how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my response.

You should include /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h (and ip.h) in user space. .../linux/*.h is used by device drivers, modules, and kernel code.

Define _BSD_SOURCE if you want to use BSD declaration.

Comment: yes. I can't compile the code since #include<linux/ip.h> shows an error "Header not found" in the Xcode itself. If I change it to <netint/ip.h> the suggestions I get are from the second structure mentioned above

Comment: Can you run 'ls /usr/include/linux/ip.h'? If you don't see the file, can you run 'sudo find /usr -name "ip.h"'?

Comment: I meant: 'ls /usr/include/linux/tcp.h' and 'sudo find /usr -name "tcp.h"'

Comment: In user space you should use netinet/tcp.h and not directly include linux/*.h . linux/*.h are generally included in kernel space code. Maybe for that reason you don't have linux/tcp.h available in your mac.